# Echo out line with a link php

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm trying to echo out a line out of my database.

The code looks like this:

```
echo '<a href="#">" . $row["contact"] . "</a><br />';
```

So, what I want, is that when the row appears on the screen, the contact line (the mail-adress) should be a linked line to the filled in contact-line.
My code does not work. The screen is just white.

Any ideas?

Comment: what errors are PHP reporting? A blank page is usually a 500 error which points to a syntax error in your script.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
 echo '<a href="#">' . $row["contact"] . '</a><br />' ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't gives a real link to the mail-adress...

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are mixed up:

```
echo '<a href="#">" . $row["contact"] . "</a><br />';
     ^            ^                     ^          ^
```

Should be:

```
echo "<a href=\"#\">" . $row["contact"] . "</a><br />";
```

Or:

```
echo '<a href="#">' . $row["contact"] . '</a><br />';
```